# First file path value not added into array on linux ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Running a python script on linux

```
pngs = []

for idx, device in enumerate(udid):
    pngs += glob.glob(os.getcwd() + "/logs/" + device + "_" + get_model_of_android_phone(device) + "/" + "*.png")

    print(glob.glob(os.getcwd() + "/logs/" + device + "_" + get_model_of_android_phone(device) + "/" + "*.png"))
```

The for loop will run twice and 2 pngs will be added into the array. 
However, only the 2nd one was added into the array.

Not too sure why the first one is missing from the array.

When i try to print the entire path, the entire path is showing.

Example of the file path

```
['/home/ubuntu/logs/123456789_SM-G920I/123456789google_search_android.png']
```

Comment: Have you tried doing an `os.listdir()` of the path? Just to make sure that they are in fact inside that directory.

Comment: The file is there but somehow my script is not detecting it

Comment: @CalderWhite Any idea if there is any command that can refresh the directory before i add the path into the array?

Comment: Print the strings you are passing to glob. Look at the first one and you might find why it doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried with append?

````
for idx, device in enumerate(udid):
    pngs.append(glob.glob(os.getcwd() + "/logs/" + device + "_" + get_model_of_android_phone(device) + "/" + "*.png"))

    print(glob.glob(os.getcwd() + "/logs/" + device + "_" + get_model_of_android_phone(device) + "/" + "*.png"))```
````